# Passing a JSON encoded PHP array to HTML onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm trying to populate my jquery datatables and I've been successful in doing so.
Except when I'm passing a JSON encoded string in one of the javascript function parameters in the html tag. I'm using the following code from PHP. As seen below, I'm passing a json_encode of the $update_data variable on the last parameter of the function in the onclick part.

```
                       $update_data = 
                            array(
                            array('Page type',array( array('1 - Standard','Standard'), array('2 - HTML','HTML') ),'select','noval'),
                            array('title',$row->title,'input','val'),
                            array('header',$row->header,'input','noval'),
                            array('footer',$row->footer,'input','noval'),
                            );

$subarray[]='<center> <span data-target="#updatepost'.$row->_id.'" data-toggle="modal" onclick="easy_update(\'update\',\'post\',\'book/update-book-folder-designation\','.$row->_id.',\'Update Pages\',\''.json_encode($update_data).'\')" class="btn fa fa-pencil"></span> </center>';
```

Then I get an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

When I'm calling the function from the onclick. But the javascript error line points to nothing.

My javascript function is simply as

```
function easy_update(type,method,url,id,header_title,data){

 }
```

I suspect it's about the formatting of the json string that causes the mess in reading the parameters of my js function but I'm not sure.
Here is the image of my rendered html tag from the inspect element

[image: rendered view]

I dont get any errors when i replace the json encoded string with a regular string as parameter. I Hope i give enough information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to use string parameter as JS object on client function `easy_update()`. Try to send the `data` without quotes like this:

```
$subarray[]='<center> <span data-target="#updatepost'.$row->_id.'" data-toggle="modal" onclick="easy_update(\'update\',\'post\',\'book/update-book-folder-designation\','.$row->_id.',\'Update Pages\','.json_encode($update_data).')" class="btn fa fa-pencil"></span> </center>';
```

Also you need to replace quotes in tags or in json_encode() results as example:

```
$var = str_replace('"', '\'', json_encode($update_data));
```

And then send it to function, One of the possible options will be:

```
$encoded = str_replace('"', '\'', json_encode($update_data));
$subarray[]='<center> <span data-target="#updatepost'.$row->_id.'" data-toggle="modal" onclick="easy_update(\'update\',\'post\',\'book/update-book-folder-designation\','.$row->_id.',\'Update Pages\','.$encoded.')" class="btn fa fa-pencil"></span> </center>';
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but I still got the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta I fixed my answer, try it now

Comment: Now it has a different error : Unexpected token P in JSON.   https://imgur.com/a/N1aFp

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta Hmm.. So you can try to define the `data` variable out of js `easy_update()` function, in another place on the client. And put values from PHP to the `data` without quote replacing. It will more convenient cause you'll not use large JS objects in the `onclick` attributes and you'll not have any troubles with quotes.